# Carousel com loop wordpress em colunas

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress, carousel

Olá, eu estou tentando ajustar o meu carousel para que ele tenha um grid feito por loop, tenho o seguinte código de wordpress:

```html
<?php 
global $posts; 
$b = 0;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'banner', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div id="carousel-front-page" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="item <?php if (0 == $b) {echo "active";} ?>">
    <?php the_content() ?>
   </div>
   <?php $b++ ?>
  <?php endwhile ?>
 </div>
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-front-page" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="icon-prev"></span>
 </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-front-page" data-slide="next">
  <span class="icon-next"></span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Funciona normalmente com loop de post type de wordpress, mas eu estou tentando agora fazer do mesmo modo, só que com um grid de col-md-3 por exemplo, com loop deixando 4 posts de inicio, e depois ir para mais quatro. E não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum fazer um loop nisso, não sei onde estou errando, sei que sem loop é fácil de fazer.

Fiz algo em cima disso, mas estou pecando em alguma coisa:

```html
<?php 
$per_page = 5;
$n=0;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'meusprodutos', 'posts_per_page' => $per_page );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if($loop->have_posts()):  
  ?>
<div class="carousel-loja">
 
   <div id="shopCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="ponteiros">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php  while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
          <li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $n++; ?>"></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ol>
    </div><!--ponteiros-->

    <!-- Carousel items --> 
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    
     <div class="row">

      <?php  while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
      
       <div class="col-md-4">   
      <div class="item <?php if (0 == $n) {echo "active";} ?>">
       
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

      </div><?php $n++ ?>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    
    
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<?php 
endif; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Como assim, *um grid de col-md-3 por exemplo, com loop deixando 4 posts de inicio, e depois ir para mais quatro.* Tipo, você quer que carregue uma vez 4 posts pra ficar no carousel, e depois quando faz um *refresh* da página, são 4 posts **diferentes**?

Comment: Na verdade, eu quero que apareça mais de 1 post de uma vez no carousel, igual a esse: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/infinite-carousel-loop mas eu não estou sabendo fazer o loop desse jeito, só com 1 imagem por vez

Comment: Ahh, agora entendi. Seu problema então está no fato que não consegue fazer aparecer mais de uma foto/post por cada vez?

Comment: Exato, isso que preciso fazer

Comment: E suponho que já tem o CSS e JS correto? O problema é simplesmente não mostar mais de uma? Se conseguir, postar o JavaScript (o `$('#mycarousel').carousel()`) e o CSS associados (não os do bootstrap)

Comment: Eu estou usando o padrão do bootstrap, o código que postei está puro, fiz um post type apenas, funciona legal 1 de cada vez, um slide padrão.. Só que agora quero montar um slide igual a esse, que apareça mais de um post por vez,  da para usar o grid do bootstrap, mas quando faz o loop é mais complicado e estou me atrapalhando

Comment: Como mencionei em minha respotsa, vê se consegue capturar algumas imagens do seu site (ou até um link se der, pra eu ver "pessoalmente").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegando o código que você me mostrou que está usando como seu exemplo:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/infinite-carousel-loop

O código principal é esse:

```html
<div class="item active">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="img-responsive">1</a></div>
</div>
```

Eu creio que o loop que está usando seja boa, embora não sei se `the_content()` contém mesmo uma imagem ou não.

Emobra disso, tenha certeza que seu CSS tenha isso:

```css
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}
.item:not(.prev) {visibility: visible;}
.item.right:not(.prev) {visibility: hidden;}
.rightest{ visibility: visible;}
```

E no seu JavaScript, tenha isso:

```js
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {

      next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)).addClass('rightest');

  }
  else {
      $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  }
});
```

Obs: Peguei esses códigos direto do site de exemplo que você mandou

Se já tem tudo isso e continua não funcionando, tenta por algumas fotos dos resultados renderizados, e inclue o JavaScript e CSS que tem, e quaisquer errors que se encontram no console do site ou no PHP.

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta com o código atual que estou tentando fazer funcionar